# How to swap text both on hover and onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a default message on the top of a donation form and I would like it to change dynamically depending on which amount the user hovers or clicks.

Each amount as well as "€Other" should have a corresponding message. For Example: "with €5.00 we can accomplish this..." With €10.00 we could do that..."

These messages should change accordingly on hover but also remain visible if the corresponding option is selected.

If the user deselects a previously selected option or if no option is selected, the default message should reappear.

I've tried different methods without success, I would really appreciate some help making this happen.

**[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/davidxmartins/bje4umbL/)**

**HTML**

```
<p>Choose below the amount of your donation</p>

<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_blank">

    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_donations">
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="louzanimalespaypal@gmail.com">

    <label><input type="checkbox" name="amount" class="checkbutton" value="5,00"><span>€05.00</span></label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="amount" class="checkbutton" value="10,00"><span>€10.00</span></label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="amount" class="checkbutton" value="15,00"><span>€15.00</span></label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="amount" class="checkbutton" value="20,00"><span>€20.00</span></label>
    <input type="number" class="textBox" name="amount" placeholder="€ Other">

    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Donation">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="Donation">
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="EUR">
    <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="PT">
    <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="Louzanimales_Donation_WPS_PT">
    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://www.louzanimales.py/agradecimentos.htm">


    <br style="clear: both;"/>
    <input class="donation-button" type="submit" value="Send Donation">

</form>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('input.checkbutton').on('change', function() {
    $('input.checkbutton').not(this).prop('checked', false);
});

$(".textBox").focus(function() {
    $(".checkbutton").prop("checked", false);
});

$(".checkbutton").change(function() {
    if($(this).is(":checked")) { 
        $(".textBox").val(""); 
    } 
});
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 50px;
    font-family: sans-serif; 
    font-size: 18px;
    text-align: center;
}

label {
    margin: 1%;
    float: left;
    background: #ccc;
    text-align: center;
    width: 18%;
}

label:hover {
    background: grey;
    color: #fff;
}

label span {
    text-align: center;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 10px 0;
    display: block;
}

label input {
    display: none;
    left: 0;
    top: -10px;
}

input:checked + span {
    background-color: black;
    color: #fff;
}

/* Hide HTML5 Up and Down arrows in input type="number" */
input[type=number] {-moz-appearance: textfield;}
input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button { 
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    margin: 0; 
}


.textBox {
    margin: 1%;
    float: left;
    background: #ccc;
    border: 0; 
    padding: 10px 0;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: sans-serif; 
    font-size: 18px;
    width: 18%;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* For legacy WebKit based browsers */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; /* For all Gecko based browsers */
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.textBox:focus {
    box-shadow:none;
    box-shadow:inset 0 0 4px 0 #000;
   -moz-box-shadow:inset 0 0 4px 0 #000;
   -wevkit-box-shadow:inset 0 0 4px 0 #000;
}

.donation-button {
    width: 98%;
    margin: 1%;
    border: 0;
    background: grey;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: sans-serif; 
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 10px 0 10px 0;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* For legacy WebKit based browsers */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; /* For all Gecko based browsers */
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.donation-button:hover {
    background: black;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

David! Finally i improved it :)
You can customize your own message in HTML seperatly by data-alertOnHover which shown on hover on button or textBox and data-alertAfter which shown select a button or type a number in textBox. It covers all of states as well as less cumbersome.

Also

> if the user deselects a previously selected option or if no option is
>   selected, the default message will reappear.

```js
var defaultTxt = $('#alert').text();
var checked;
$('input.checkbutton').change(function() {
  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    $(".textBox").val("");
   $('#alert').text($(this).attr("data-alertAfter") + $(this).val());
    checked = $(this);
  }
  else
  {
   $('#alert').text(defaultTxt);
    checked = undefined;
  }
  $('input.checkbutton').not(this).prop('checked', false);
});
$('.input-container').hover(
  function() {
    $('#alert').text($(this).children('input').attr("data-alertOnHover"));
  },
  function() {
    if (checked)
     $('#alert').text($(checked).attr("data-alertAfter") + $(checked).val());
    else
     $('#alert').text(defaultTxt);
  }
);
$(".textBox").focus(function() {
  checked = undefined;
 $(".checkbutton").prop("checked", false)
}).blur(function() {
  if ($(this).val() != "") {
   checked = $(this);
   $('#alert').text($(this).attr("data-alertAfter") + $(this).val())
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 50px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
}

label {
  margin: 1%;
  float: left;
  background: #ccc;
  text-align: center;
  width: 18%;
}

label:hover {
  background: grey;
  color: #fff;
}

label span {
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px 0;
  display: block;
}

label input {
  display: none;
  left: 0;
  top: -10px;
}

input:checked + span {
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
}


/* Hide HTML5 Up and Down arrows in input type="number" */

input[type=number] {
  -moz-appearance: textfield;
}

input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
}

.textBox {
  margin: 1%;
  float: left;
  background: #ccc;
  border: 0;
  padding: 10px 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  width: 18%;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  /* For legacy WebKit based browsers */
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  /* For all Gecko based browsers */
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.textBox:focus {
  box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 4px 0 #000;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 4px 0 #000;
  -wevkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 4px 0 #000;
}

.donation-button {
  width: 98%;
  margin: 1%;
  border: 0;
  background: grey;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 10px 0 10px 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  /* For legacy WebKit based browsers */
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  /* For all Gecko based browsers */
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.donation-button:hover {
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="alert">Choose below the amount of your donation</p>

<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_blank">

  <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_donations">
  <input type="hidden" name="business" value="louzanimalespaypal@gmail.com">

  <label class="input-container">
    <input type="checkbox" name="amount" class="checkbutton" value="5,00" data-alertOnHover="With €5.00 we can accomplish this..." data-alertAfter="Your donation will be €"><span>€05.00</span></label>
  <label class="input-container">
    <input type="checkbox" name="amount" class="checkbutton" value="10,00" data-alertOnHover="With €10.00 we could do that..." data-alertAfter="Your donation will be €"><span>€10.00</span></label>
  <label class="input-container">
    <input type="checkbox" name="amount" class="checkbutton" value="15,00" data-alertOnHover="With €15.00 we could do that..." data-alertAfter="Your donation will be €"><span>€15.00</span></label>
  <label class="input-container">
    <input type="checkbox" name="amount" class="checkbutton" value="20,00" data-alertOnHover="With €20,00 we could do more than that..." data-alertAfter="Your donation will be €"><span>€20.00</span></label>
  <span class="input-container">
    <input type="number" class="textBox" name="amount" placeholder="€ Other" data-alertOnHover="just type how much you want to donate..." data-alertAfter="Your donation will be €">
  </span>

  <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Donation">
  <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="Donation">
  <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="EUR">
  <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="PT">
  <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="Louzanimales_Donation_WPS_PT">
  <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://www.louzanimales.py/agradecimentos.htm">


  <br style="clear: both;" />
  <input class="donation-button" type="submit" value="Send Donation">

</form>
```

Comment: Wow! I really couldn't ask for anything more. This exactly what I was looking for. Thank you ever so much for all your help. Best wishes!

Comment: Thanks and Good luck

Answer (score 2):

You can use data attributes for input fields, and data can hold text. Also, to achieve desired functionality, you could set 'flag' which will check if option is selected and 'lock' text (so it will not change on hover). Something like this:

```js
locked=false;
$('input.checkbutton').on('change', function() {
 $('#desc').text( $(this).data('text') );
if($(this).prop('checked')) {
locked=true;
}
else {
locked=false;
}
    $('input.checkbutton').not(this).prop('checked', false);
   
});

$(".textBox").focus(function() {
    $(".checkbutton").prop("checked", false);
});

$(".checkbutton").change(function() {
    if($(this).is(":checked")) { 
        $(".textBox").val(""); 
    } 
});
default_text="Choose below the amount of your donation";

$( 'label').hover(
  function() {

  if(!locked)
    $('#desc').text( $(this).children().data('text') );
  }, function() {
  if(!locked)
     $('#desc').text( default_text );
  }
);
```

```css
body {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 50px;
    font-family: sans-serif; 
    font-size: 18px;
    text-align: center;
}

label {
    margin: 1%;
    float: left;
    background: #ccc;
    text-align: center;
    width: 18%;
}

label:hover {
    background: grey;
    color: #fff;
}

label span {
    text-align: center;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 10px 0;
    display: block;
}

label input {
    display: none;
    left: 0;
    top: -10px;
}

input:checked + span {
    background-color: black;
    color: #fff;
}

/* Hide HTML5 Up and Down arrows in input type="number" */
input[type=number] {-moz-appearance: textfield;}
input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button { 
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    margin: 0; 
}


.textBox {
    margin: 1%;
    float: left;
    background: #ccc;
    border: 0; 
    padding: 10px 0;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: sans-serif; 
    font-size: 18px;
    width: 18%;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* For legacy WebKit based browsers */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; /* For all Gecko based browsers */
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.textBox:focus {
    box-shadow:none;
    box-shadow:inset 0 0 4px 0 #000;
   -moz-box-shadow:inset 0 0 4px 0 #000;
   -wevkit-box-shadow:inset 0 0 4px 0 #000;
}

.donation-button {
    width: 98%;
    margin: 1%;
    border: 0;
    background: grey;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: sans-serif; 
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 10px 0 10px 0;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* For legacy WebKit based browsers */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; /* For all Gecko based browsers */
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.donation-button:hover {
    background: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="desc">Choose below the amount of your donation</p>

<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_blank">

    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_donations">
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="louzanimalespaypal@gmail.com">

    <label><input type="checkbox" name="amount" class="checkbutton" value="5,00" data-text="With 5 euros we can..."><span>€05.00</span></label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="amount" class="checkbutton" value="10,00" data-text="With 10 euros we can..."><span>€10.00</span></label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="amount" class="checkbutton" value="15,00" data-text="With 15 euros we can..."><span>€15.00</span></label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="amount" class="checkbutton" value="20,00" data-text="With 20 euros we can..."><span>€20.00</span></label>
    <input type="number" class="textBox" name="amount" placeholder="€ Other">

    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Donation">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="Donation">
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="EUR">
    <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="PT">
    <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="Louzanimales_Donation_WPS_PT">
    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://www.louzanimales.py/agradecimentos.htm">


    <br style="clear: both;"/>
    <input class="donation-button" type="submit" value="Send Donation">

</form>
```

P.S. If i didn't understand your requirements, and you want text changing on hover, even when option is selected, you can just remove `locked` var...

EDIT: I think it is perfect now: https://jsfiddle.net/y05uzdzc/ based on your description.

Comment: Thank you so much. Not knowing anything of JavaScript I can only evaluate replies based on performance, and from what I see here, you were the one that came closer to what I'm looking for. To make this perfect, only two things are missing: 1. yes. it would make sense in terms of usability for the text to change on hover even when an option is selected. 2. The "€Other" option should display the original text. Your help is greatly appreciated, this is for an animal rescue organization and I'm doing this for free. Thank you again.

Comment: @David Martins, Np, please check edit. I think that's it, now. ;) I've added one function to cover behavior based on mouseout from paypalform - when option is selected - > show selected option text, otherwise: default....

Comment: Is this in your opinion a better solution then the one provided by @mohamad faramarzi ? I'm trying to make the most well informed choice here in terms of voting the best solution... I also like his feature with a personalized message for "€Other"...

Comment: Well, if both codes are working - compare and choose what you like more. :)

Answer (score 2):

i think this is exactly do what you need.
[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/Lzoortk5/)

HTML is not changed but "id" of:

```
<p id="alert">Choose below the amount of your donation</p>
```

Javascript

```
var defaultTxt = $('#alert').text();
$('input.checkbutton').change( function() {
    $('input.checkbutton').not(this).prop('checked', false);
    if($(this).is(":checked")) { 
        $(".textBox").val(""); 
    }
    var check = $(this).prop('checked');
    var value = $(this).val();
    switch(value)
    {
        case("5,00"):
            if(check)
                $('#alert').text("with €5.00 we can accomplish this...");
            else
                $('#alert').text(defaultTxt);
        break;
        case("10,00"):
            if(check)
                $('#alert').text("With €10.00 we could do that...");
            else
                $('#alert').text(defaultTxt);
        break;
        case("15,00"):
            if(check)
                $('#alert').text("With €15.00 we could do that...");
            else
                $('#alert').text(defaultTxt);
        break;
        case("20,00"):
            if(check)
                $('#alert').text("With €20,00 we could do more than that...");
            else
                $('#alert').text(defaultTxt);
        break;
        default:
        $('#alert').text("");
        break;
    }
});

$('input.checkbutton').hover(function() {
    alert();
  },function() {

  }
);
$('input.checkbutton').parent().hover( 
    function() {
    var value = $(this).children('input.checkbutton').val();
    switch(value)
    {
        case("5,00"):
        $('#alert').text("with €5.00 we can accomplish this...");
        break;
        case("10,00"):
        $('#alert').text("With €10.00 we could do that...");
        break;
        case("15,00"):
        $('#alert').text("With €15.00 we could do that...");
        break;
        case("20,00"):
        $('#alert').text("With €20,00 we could do more than that...");
        break;
        default:
        $('#alert').text("");
        break;
    }
  }, function() {
    var othervalue = $('input.checkbutton:checked').val();
    switch(othervalue)
    {
        case("5,00"):
        $('#alert').text("with €5.00 we can accomplish this...");
        break;
        case("10,00"):
        $('#alert').text("With €10.00 we could do that...");
        break;
        case("15,00"):
        $('#alert').text("With €15.00 we could do that...");
        break;
        case("20,00"):
        $('#alert').text("With €20,00 we could do more than that...");
        break;
        default:
        $('#alert').text("");
        break;
    }
  }
);
$(".textBox").focus(function() {
    $(".checkbutton").prop("checked", false);
    $('#alert').text(defaultTxt);
});
$(".textBox").blur(function() {
        var txtVal = $(this).val();
        if(txtVal != "")
            $('#alert').text("With €"+ txtVal +" we could do that");
});
```

Comment: why should i give "this answer is not useful"??? it's nice if i know where was i wrong.

Comment: This is precisely what I need in terms of performance, and I like the fact that I get a personalized message for "€Other" as well, which was my initial requirement. I've voted up your reply! My only hesitation is choosing this as the best solution is because @sinisake solution seams to have a lot less lines of code. I find my self in an awkward position of having to evaluate two different solutions that basically do the same, when I'm not knowledgeable enough to choose one over the other...

Comment: thanks for comment, actually it was important to me not changing your html code as far as i can. but if you want i can use data-message attribute (@sinisake solution) to make it lighter.

Comment: Mohamad thank you for your efforts, if you're up to it please do it in a separate reply so viewer have this alternative as a choice as well. To me the data-message attribute solution seems less cumbersome, so if you can provide it wile kipping the "€other" personalized message as well, I think that it would be my choice.

Comment: do you prefer to show different message on hover and on change for each button and textBox?

Comment: Exactly what you have at the moment, in terms of performance it is perfect, could't be any better.

Answer (score 0):

When I run into stuff like this, I pick or create a way to easily distinguish one input from the others.

Unique ID's make it quick, and easy to find.  In this example, your 5 Euro donation would get the ID of donation-5.

```
$("body").on("mouseover", "input", function () {
    if ($(this).attr("id") === "donation-5") {
        //  --> DO your hover thing.
    } else if (so forth and so on...){
        // .....
    }
})
```

Also, I'd consider using HTML5 button tags.

**Ah yes... Nearly forgot, you want to monitor two event types**

You'll need two 'event listeners':

*The one I listed above,* as well as the one that follows:

```
$("body").on("click", "input", function () {
    if ($(this).attr("id") === "donation-5") {
        //  --> DO your hover thing.
    } else if (so forth and so on...){
        // .....
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I think you want radio buttons instead of checkboxes. Once you make that change, I would just capture the `change` and `hover` events.

On change, you can always update your message. On hover, see if any of the items are checked, if so, leave the message, otherwise you can change it.

Here's a running example:

```js
$(".donation").hover(function() {
  let checkCount = $("form .donation :checked").length;
  if (checkCount == 0) {
    setMessage(this);
  }
}).change(function() {
  setMessage(this);
});

function setMessage(item) {
  var text = $(item).text();
  $("#message").text("Thanks for pledge of " + text);
}
```

```css
body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 50px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
}
label {
  margin: 1%;
  float: left;
  background: #ccc;
  text-align: center;
  width: 18%;
}
label:hover {
  background: grey;
  color: #fff;
}
label span {
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px 0;
  display: block;
}
label input {
  display: none;
  left: 0;
  top: -10px;
}
input:checked + span {
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
}
/* Hide HTML5 Up and Down arrows in input type="number" */

input[type=number] {
  -moz-appearance: textfield;
}
input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
}
.textBox {
  margin: 1%;
  float: left;
  background: #ccc;
  border: 0;
  padding: 10px 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  width: 18%;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  /* For legacy WebKit based browsers */
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  /* For all Gecko based browsers */
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.textBox:focus {
  box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 4px 0 #000;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 4px 0 #000;
  -wevkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 4px 0 #000;
}
.donation-button {
  width: 98%;
  margin: 1%;
  border: 0;
  background: grey;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 10px 0 10px 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  /* For legacy WebKit based browsers */
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  /* For all Gecko based browsers */
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.donation-button:hover {
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="message">Choose below the amount of your donation</p>

<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_blank">

  <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_donations">
  <input type="hidden" name="business" value="louzanimalespaypal@gmail.com">

  <label class="donation">
    <input type="radio" name="amount" class="checkbutton" value="5,00"><span>€05.00</span>
  </label>
  <label class="donation">
    <input type="radio" name="amount" class="checkbutton" value="10,00"><span>€10.00</span>
  </label>
  <label class="donation">
    <input type="radio" name="amount" class="checkbutton" value="15,00"><span>€15.00</span>
  </label>
  <label class="donation">
    <input type="radio" name="amount" class="checkbutton" value="20,00"><span>€20.00</span>
  </label>
  <input type="number" class="textBox" name="amount" placeholder="€ Other">

  <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Donation">
  <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="Donation">
  <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="EUR">
  <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="PT">
  <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="Louzanimales_Donation_WPS_PT">
  <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://www.louzanimales.py/agradecimentos.htm">


  <br style="clear: both;" />
  <input class="donation-button" type="submit" value="Send Donation">

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, do not trust that clicking is the only of way of selecting a checkbox. An user can very well tab his way to it and spacebar its change.

Secondly, the behavior you want is radio button, not checkboxes.

This is how I'd do it:

**HTML**

```
<p id="myTextIdentifier">Choose below the amount of your donation</p>
... <!- Hidden for brevity ->

<label><input type="radio" name="amount" data-message="Value is 5 message" value="5,00"><span>€05.00</span></label>
<label><input type="radio" name="amount" data-message="Value is 10 message" value="10,00"><span>€10.00</span></label>
<label><input type="radio" name="amount" data-message="Value is 15 message" value="15,00"><span>€15.00</span></label>
<label><input type="radio" name="amount" data-message="Value is 20 message" value="20,00"><span>€20.00</span></label>
<input type="number" name="amount" data-message="Other value message" placeholder="€ Other">
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('#otherValueIdentifier')
    .focus(function() {
        $(':radio').prop('checked', false);
    })
    .change(function() {
        changeText($(this).val().length
                     ? $(this).data('message')
                     : '');
    });

$(':radio').change(function() {
    changeText($(this).is(':checked')
                 ? $(this).data('message')
                 : '');
});

// Please keep in mind that this has a few flaws, I'll revise it later
$('[data-message]').hover(function () {
   // this is the mouseEnter function
   changeText($(this).data('message'));

}, function() {
   // this is the mouseLeave function
   changeText($('[data-message]:checked').data('message'));
});

function changeText(text) {
    $('#myTextIdentifier').val(text || 'Default message');
}
```